# Is it possible to get response in array form in ajax-php

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to ajax, i am trying to get the price and total depend of item selected ,i have tried to do this in my code .but one question arise,Is it possible to get response in array form in ajax-php .Because depending on item ,price and total will be displayed in the respected input boxes . is it possible?

**process.php**

```
    extract($_POST);
         switch($_POST['item']){
         case "Course1":
         $price=45;
         $total= ($qty*$price).'$';
         $arr=array('price'=>'45$','total'=>$total);
         break;

         case "Course2":
         $price=30;
         $total= ($qty*$price).'$';
         $arr=array('price'=>'30$','total'=>$total);
         break;
        }
```

**index.php**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#item').change(function(){

    var act = $('#myform').attr('action');
    var data = $('#myform').serialize();
    $.post('process.php',data, function(info){$('#price').val(info);});

    });

    });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="col_w450 float_l">
                   <div id='pre'></div>

                        <h4><u>Ajax Practice</u></h4>

                        <form method="post" name="contact" id="myform" action="process.php" >

                            <label for="author">Item:</label> 
                            <select name="item"id="item">
                            <option value=''>Select</option>
                            <option value='Course1'>Course1</option>
                            <option value='Course2'>Course2</option>
                            </select>

                            <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                            <br>
                            <label for="email">Price:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                            <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                            <br>
                            <label for="text">Quantity:</label> 

                            <select name="qty"id="qty">
                            <option value='1'>1</option>
                            <option value='2'>2</option>
                            <option value='3'>3</option>
                            <option value='4'>4</option>
                            <option value='5'>5</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                            <br>
                            <label for="email">Total:</label> 
                            <input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                            <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                            <br>

                        </form>

                    </div> 
                </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

**Edit 2**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#item').change(function(){

var act = $('#myform').attr('action');
var data = $('#myform').serialize();
$.post('process.php',$('#myform').serialize(), function(data){

var res = $.parseJSON(data);
var response_data=JSON.stringify(res.result);
var arr=[]; 
arr = response_data.split(","); 


 alert(arr["price"]);


//$('#price')esutl.val(info);
});

});

});

</script>
```

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: Use json_endcode at process.php and parseJSON at index.php

Comment: from process.php, i want to get array containing price and total and display in index.php in respected input boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use to encode the array like in process.php

```
$data['result'] = $arr;
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

And in the success function of ajax try to get it like parseJSON like

```
success:function(data){
    var res = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(res.result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but iam getting [object object]  when i alert(res.result)

Comment: var response_data=JSON.stringify(res.result);
alert(response_data);

Comment: how to get two value seperately i have tried alert(response_data.total);

Comment: var arr=[]; 
arr = response_data.split(",");

Comment: how to alert array,i want to get value seperately,so that i candisplay in respected input field

Comment: after spliting you can alert the array using alert(arr);

Comment: i am getting o/p as {"price":"45$","total":"45$"}, iam updating the present code

Comment: arr["price"]=>"45$"
arr["total"]=>"45$"
  You can use this according to your need

Comment: alert(arr["price"]);  will give you o/p 45$

Comment: i have used arr["price"]=>"45$" arr["total"]=>"45$"  ,but getting undefined,as array is not splitted,please check code in edit 2 above,whether i have done correctly or not

Comment: alert(res.result["price"]); is giving correct o/p ie $45